# troubles with sql query

Tags: sql, debugging, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I've got a table of suppliers and table of products. I need to delete a supplier and then all products and its amount add to another supplier. For example

table supplier. I delete supplier 1

```
sup1 idsup1
sup2 idsup2
sup3 idsup3
```

table products.(idpr - foreign key)

```
idpr1 amount1 idsup1
idpr1 amount2 idsup3
idpr1 amount3 idsup2
idpr2 amount4 idsup2
```

I need to add all amount of supplier1's products to supplier2 so this table will be like this

```
idpr1 amount2 idsup3
idpr1 amount3+amount1 idsup2 
idpr2 amount4 idsup2
```

But how to do it?I don't understand how to sum all products with the same idpr. I set  idsup2 for all records with idsup1. But is there another way?

Comment: which engine are you using? Also, please provide exact describe result

Comment: You're going to need a sub-query in the RHS of the SET clause of your UPDATE statement to do this, I believe.  The first step, though, is to work out the SELECT statement that will give you the correct answers.  With that in hand, you can develop the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how to sum all products with the same idpr.

Use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause with the column name in the `SUM` function, as in this example:

```
SELECT 'site://tags/' + TargetTagName + '/synonyms|' + TargetTagName AS [VOTE4ME], Count(SourceTagName) AS [SYNONYMS]
FROM TagSynonyms TS
WHERE
ApprovalDate IS NULL
AND
(SELECT SUM(
 CASE V.VoteTypeId 
 WHEN 2 THEN 1 
 WHEN 3 THEN -1 
 END) 
 FROM TAGS T, PostTags Pt, Posts P, Votes V, VoteTypes Vt
 WHERE T.Id = Pt.TagId
 AND P.Id = V.PostId
 AND Pt.PostId = P.ParentId
 AND Vt.Id = V.VoteTypeId
 AND T.TagName = TargetTagName
 AND P.OwnerUserId = ##userid##
 AND P.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL
) > 4
GROUP BY TargetTagName
```

**References**

- [My List of Tag Synonyms which Permit Voting](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/159698/my-list-of-tag-synonyms-which-permit-voting)